# How I can put a a GtkSwitch in a cell (column) of GtkTreeView?

Tags: c++, gtkmm

How I can put a a GtkSwitch in a cell (column) of GtkTreeView?
This is possible?

Comment: Is it possible to put objects other than GtkSwitch in a GtkTreeView?  What prevents you from doing the same with a GtkSwitch?

Comment: Do you know any example in GTKMM?

Answer (score 1):

Not really, no. You can only put GtkCellRenderers in GtkTreeView columns. To get something like it, you'd have to implement a custom GtkCellRenderer, which would be very very difficult, and it might be impossible to get the exact same behaviour. GtkCellRendererToggle will give you a check box instead though.

Here are the available standard cell renderers:
https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkCellRenderer.html#GtkCellRenderer.object-hierarchy